# How to transform a series of numbers to new min and max in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

First off I apologize if my question is confusing. I'm not quite sure how to word what my objective is. But I can definitely show it.

I have this sequence of numbers. Let's just assume this sequence starts at A1 and finishes at A57

```
31.452
44.52855
44.57402
44.59986
44.6226
44.63087
44.6381
44.62157
44.59779
44.54612
44.49237
44.4314
44.36732
44.30427
44.24019
44.18438
44.12961
44.09447
44.05622
43.98905
43.89499
43.76994
43.59837
43.38443
43.12708
42.82633
42.49973
42.14213
41.82587
41.55199
41.37939
41.37629
41.55509
41.91992
42.50567
43.31687
44.41017
45.77972
47.35682
49.01285
50.84865
52.76339
54.65035
56.62502
58.48567
60.40772
62.21283
64.00625
65.67835
67.29199
68.83255
70.26056
71.65934
73.02889
74.3239
75.60721
84.88795
```

Where `31.452` is the max value and `84.88795` is the min value.

I would like to transform everything so that `31.452` becomes `1` and `84.88795` becomes `-3`. And all the numbers in between this new min and max are correctly sequenced based on how they currently are sequenced within this present min and max.

So i'm looking for a google sheets formula to achieve this.

As a loose example:

```
1
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
correct number
-3
```

Hopefully this question makes a little more sense now.

Comment: Is the 1 and -3 dependent specifically on the 31.452 and 84.88795? Or should it work with any min/max numbers?

Comment: It's dependent on those exact numbers. Basically I have a graph. The bottom of the graph has the y axis coordinates of `84.88795`, and the top of the graph has the y axis coordinates of `31.452`. The actual values at the bottom of the graph start at `-3` and the top end at `1`. I'm wanting to transform the y axis coordinates to the actual graph values by transforming them so everything is correctly represented how they are relative to one another. If that makes sense. If you can help me with this I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Basically imagine `84.88795` is 0% and `31.452` is 100%. I want to be able to find out what percentage the rest of the numbers would be in the sequence between both these min and max values. But instead of 0% to 100%, it goes -3 to 1.

Comment: Could you please provide a sheet with the desired outcome. It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this formula in B2 and autogenerate it for the cells below.

```
=((A1-MIN(A:A))*(4/(MAX(A:A)-MIN(A:A)))-1)*(-1)
```

Is this the desired result?

[image]

Comment: These didn't work